# PHP CURL POST data with value empty

Tags: php, json, curl, post

I have this code to POST data to an url that is receiving the data with below, with content-type header set as text/html

```
file_get_contents("php://input");
```

This is the code That I used to POST to url and it is sending the data, but without values (i'm sending an array data with key values).

```
$url = "http://url im sending data to";

$object = array(
   "key1" => "123",
   "key2" => "345",
   "key3" => "567"
);

$data = http_build_query($object, '', '&');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

However, it's sending the data, but without the values, since I get a response back from the url saying that values are empty.

Moreover, I checked the curl_errno($ch) and it doesn't return anything so there is no error within my code (I think?)

Can someone help me out?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved the problem and it was pretty simple.

Just swap the http_build_query with json_encode, and make sure to only set the curl_setopt as it is.

add the bottom code also.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
```

I don't know why but for some reason, if I add other curl_setopt variables like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

it does not work.